# How to make text to be located in the middle of that cell in the Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I am using standard library

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

And this is how I create Excel, just small part of code:

```
//Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel._Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

//add data 
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Student1";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Student2";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Student3";
```

What should I do to make text in the cell be located in the middle?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range RangeYour= workSheet1.Range["B3:I3"];
          //  rngcompphon.Merge();
          //  rngcompphon.ShrinkToFit = true;
            rngcompphon.VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            rngcompphon.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
           // rngcompphon.Font.Bold = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

set like this for the range:

```
Range("B2").Style.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
```

Vertical alignment is similarly available as:

```
Range("B2").Style.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
```

Comment: If you are `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` then alignment is `Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter`